# How to hide various span tags with a known id leaving just one visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this page where I have some span tags that works like a link, inside it I have some hidden divs, what I want to do is when I click in one of these links the div inside of the clicked one is shown and the other spans receive the property `display:none`.

Like this:

```
<style>
#divHidden{display:none;}
</style>
<span id="link_01" onclick="myfunction()"> <!--<<= when clicked-->
<div id="divHidden">Content</div>          <!--<<= this comes visible-->
</span>
<span id="link_02" onclick="myfunction()"> <!--<<= then this-->
<div id="divHidden">Content</div>
</span>
<span id="link_03" onclick="myfunction()"> <!--<<= and this goes hidden-->
<div id="divHidden">Content</div>
</span>
```

how do I code this in javascript?

Comment: What did you try? Please do something before and tell us what the error with that is.

Comment: You shouldn't reapeat ids in your tags. Use a class for that instead.

Comment: If you can use bootstrap then what you are looking at is called as accordion.Check out the documentation : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: No its not an accordion. its more like I was removing the link from the page. But it's still there hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

UPDATE: to work as request, hope this is ok
[codepen version](http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/QEYROa)

```js
$('.content-wrapper').on('click','.tag', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var selectedDiv = $(this).prop('id');
  $('.content-wrapper span:not(#' + selectedDiv + ')').hide();
  $(this).find('.content').addClass('show');
})
```

```css
span.tag .content {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

span.tag .content.show {
  display: block;
}


span.tag {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #444;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  transition: background 600ms;
  display: block;
}
span.tag:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <span class="tag" id="tag-one">
    <div class="content">Content A</div>   
  </span>
  <span class="tag" id="tag-two">
    <div class="content">Content B</div>   
  </span>
  <span class="tag" id="tag-thre">
    <div class="content">Content C</div>   
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, not like that, What I want is when I click in the first link the second and third turn invisible not only the content, but the link itself, like it was removed, letting just the first link and its content visible.

Comment: so it only shows the link and content of that link you select but initially the content for all are hidden too.

Comment: I think Simon Davies has given a start which can be easily tweak around to match the requirement.

Comment: yes, the link 1, link2 , link 3 are visible, their contents not, but when one link is clicked the content of it is shown and the other links disappear, leaving only the link clicked and the content inside it.

Comment: That's it, that's what I was talking about, thanks .